# RxJava2 Flowable onErrorReturn not called

Tags: kotlin, exception, broadcastreceiver, rx-java2

Say I need to wrap `BroadcastReceiver` with Flowable:

```
        Flowable
                .create<Boolean>({ emitter ->
                    val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                            throw RuntimeException("Test exception")
                        }
                    }
                    application.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION))
                }, BackpressureStrategy.MISSING)
                .onErrorReturn { false }
```

Then I need to catch any exceptions thrown inside Flowable in one single place.

I supposed `onErrorReturn` should be able to catch that `throw RuntimeException("Test exception")` inside broadcastReceiver but it doesn't catch that exception and app crashes.

Certainly, I can wrap anything inside BroadcastReceiver with `try/catch`. But actually, I have a lot of source code there so that adding `try/catch` makes source code quite messy.

Is there any way to catch all the exceptions thrown in any line inside Flowable in one single place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of [`Flowable#create()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#create-io.reactivex.FlowableOnSubscribe-io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy-) to follow contract of `Flowable` if you have error and want to pass it through stream, you need to catch it and call `emitter.onError()`. If you do that, `Flowable.onErrorReturn()` starts work as expected.

To properly register/unregister `BroadcastReceiver` and handle exceptions you can use that approach

```
Flowable
        .create<Boolean>({ emitter ->
            val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                    try {
                        throw RuntimeException("Test exception")
                    } catch(e: Throwable) {
                        emitter.tryOnError(e)
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                application.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION))

                emitter.setCancellable {
                    application.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
                }
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                emitter.tryOnError(e)
            }
        }, BackpressureStrategy.MISSING)
        .onErrorReturn { false }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Seems like try/catch is absolutely necessary in this case. I guess there's need to also add another try/catch to `application.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)` because this code crashes the app https://gist.github.com/eugenebrusov/8ec243835474685934c3916ece7ab7f1#file-gistfile1-txt-L16

Comment: @EugeneBrusov, according to documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver) shouldn't throw exception, but you can wrap it in try/catch